# Linux keyboard raw reading, what's better, reading from /dev/input/event0 or reading from stdin?

Tags: c, linux, input, io, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a small C videogames library for the Raspberry Pi. I'm coding the input system from scratch and after reading and seeing some examples about raw input reading, I got some doubts.

For mouse reading, I just use /dev/input/event1, I open() it as O_NONBLOCK, I read() input_event(s) and I also put the mouse reading in a separate pthread. Easy.

For keyboard reading, I saw some examples that reconfigure stdin to O_NONBLOCK (using fcntl()), then save and reconfigure keyboard termios attibutes (ICANON, ECHO), and some example also save and reconfigure keyboard mode with ioctl(). What's the point of doing all that stuff instead of just reading /dev/input/event0 input_event(s) (same way as mouse)?

Note that I undestand what those functions do, I just don't undestand why should be better to do all that stuff instead of just reading input_event(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading stdin is not limited to reading locally connected keyboards (but has other limitation making it mostly unsuitable for games). Then reading stdin you could be reading keystrokes from a user logged in remotely, using a locally connected serial terminal or a terminal emulator (possibly operated from a remote X server).

For terminal based games it might make sense to use stdin. But then it would probably be better to use [GPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPM_(software)) instead of reading /dev/input/event1 for the mouse. And possibly even better to use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) for everything.

Otherwise you might want to look at [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/), if not for using it directly, at least for learning about different ways to read input. For example, SDL has full support for network transparency using X. Which means a game can execute on one computer but be played on another.

Comment: +1 Small nit - X11 don't have a 'real' transparency for some time now - especially for anything involving most extensions including OGL ones. In practice for anything complicated you need to use just server and separate protocol (like [vnc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) or [virtualgl](http://www.virtualgl.org/)).

Comment: Thanks to you all for your answers! ncurses looks interesting but my engine is not for terminal (it uses EGL+OpenGLES2.0 without X-window). The tip about checking SDL code was very useful and illustrative, thanks!

Comment: @Ray SFML (http://www.sfml-dev.org) is a more "modern" take on SDL that uses C++. I don't know how well it runs on the Pi, though. I've used it (and taught it) on a Windows/Linux desktop environment, and it's a fantastic library for 2D games.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Fabel answer - standard input and `event1` are entirely different things. Starting from that the `event1` does not have to be mouse but can be an other device depending on udev, kernel version, phase of moon etc. - on my (non Raspberry Pi) system it's `input device Sleep Button` - which has a keyboard interface. In short you cannot and should not assume it's keyboard - or the only keyboard for that matter (for example also YubiKey emulates the keyboard for it's function but it's rather useless as gaming device, and while 2 keyboards are rarely connected to same Raspberry Pi I don't think it's good idea to assume such setup never happens).

Furthermore typically input devices can be read only by privileged user (on older/current systems) or by user holding a 'seat' (on rootless X systems) - assuming you're not using bleeding edge system it means your game can only by used by root user which is usually considered a [**bad** idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/concern-about-logging-in-as-root-overrated/1062#1062).

Finally it only allows for user to play using a evdev subsystem, which probably should be considered Linux/X11 implementation detail. If you try to connect via network (X11, vnc or whaterver), try to use on-screen keyboard or any [accessible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessibility) input program - you might run into problems.

On the other hand what you can do is either use standard input directly, use some more portable libraries like [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) (which should be sufficient for [rougulike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike)) or use graphics server (probably indirectly via library like [QT](http://qt-project.org/) or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) as [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) is not the nicest protocol to program against).

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, really useful too!

Comment: What about `setgid` on the executable to run it in the `input` group (if your flavor has it) instead of running as root?

Answer (score 1):

Reading from `/dev/input/eventN` works only on GNU/Linux.

Configuring and using stdin works on any system implementing [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), specifically chapter [11: General Terminal Interface](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html).  So if you want portable code, like say to work on Linux and OS X without rewriting the input system, you'd do it this way.