# boost::asio read from /dev/input/event0

Tags: c++, boost, debian, boost-asio, keypad

I am looking to use boost::asio to read from a 12 digit keypad.  I currently can do it without boost, this way:

```
fd = open ("/dev/input/event0", 0_NONBLOCK);
read (fd, &ev, sizeof ev);
```

Do you know how I could do this with boost::asio?  I am using Linux and c++.  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001387/how-to-use-asio-with-device-files) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686127/async-wait-on-file-descriptor-using-boost-asio) are useful. I would not use serial port port (io, "/dev/usb/hiddev0") because its not serial, right?

Thank you.

Comment: I could open the device, get a file descriptor, then use that in asio I think

Comment: `Boost.Asio` provides modern C++ interfaces, but in its implementation it uses plain C (or OS) functions. So, first of all, it's worth understanding why the above `read` doesn't work. What behavior do you observe?

Comment: Highly relevant: consider using a library instead of going to the raw device: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25559167/85371

Comment: @IgorR. I cannot open the device this way: serial_port port (io, "/dev/usb/hiddev0"); I think I should use stream_descriptor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my system, `event2` represents the mouse, and the following simple `readloop` program works like a charm.

**Run as root**:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/posix/stream_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <iostream>      // for debug output
#include <iomanip>

#include <linux/input.h> // for input_event
#include <boost/range/adaptor/sliced.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;

struct input {
    using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
    using sliced = boost::adaptors::sliced;

    input(const char* devspec) : svc(), sd(svc, open(devspec, O_RDONLY)) {
        readloop(); // post work
    }

    void run() {
        svc.run();
    }

  private:
    io_service svc;
    posix::stream_descriptor sd;

    std::vector<input_event> events;

    void handle_input(error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!ec) {
            auto const n = bytes_transferred / sizeof(input_event);

            for (auto& ev : events | sliced(0,n)) {
                using namespace boost::posix_time;

                ptime ts({1970,1,1}, seconds(ev.time.tv_sec) + microsec(ev.time.tv_usec));

                std::cout << std::dec << ts.time_of_day() << "\t" << std::hex 
                          << std::hex << ev.type << " " << ev.code  << " " << ev.value << "\n";
            }

            std::cout << "\n";

            readloop();
        } else {
            std::cerr << ec.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

    void readloop() {
        events.resize(32);
        sd.async_read_some(buffer(events), boost::bind(&input::handle_input, this, placeholders::error, placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

};

int main()
{
    input monitor("/dev/input/event2");
    monitor.run();
}
```

Typical output:

```
22:33:09.705346 2 0 ffffffff
22:33:09.705346 2 1 1
22:33:09.705346 0 0 0

22:33:09.713412 2 0 ffffffff
22:33:09.713412 2 1 1
22:33:09.713412 0 0 0

22:33:09.721308 2 0 ffffffff
22:33:09.721308 0 0 0

22:33:09.729328 2 0 ffffffff
22:33:09.729328 0 0 0

22:33:09.737346 2 1 1
22:33:09.737346 0 0 0

22:33:09.745328 2 0 ffffffff
22:33:09.745328 2 1 1
22:33:09.745328 0 0 0

22:33:11.897301 4 4 90001
22:33:11.897301 1 110 1
22:33:11.897301 0 0 0

22:33:12.065294 4 4 90001
22:33:12.065294 1 110 0
22:33:12.065294 0 0 0
```

Comment: You should probably not accept it as "the solution" until you tried it :)

Comment: I've updated to actually decode the events, printing friendly µs timestamps and event batches. _(This is a poster-child for how Asio transparently uses a vector of POD structs as a write buffer.)_

Comment: Possibly date_time. (You could contrast with the [first version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27827955/1) perhaps)

Comment: Looks like all the include dirs are redundant `/usr/include/` is on it. So `g++ -x c++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -m32 -c asio_event_reader.cc -o asio_event_reader.o` makes more sense typically.

Comment: hello sir; I have gotten your code to work; can you explain how your `handle_input` function works please?

Comment: @xinthose The loop just loops through the `events` vector. The `events | sliced(0,n)` expression takes the first `n` elements (namely, the number of events transferred). You could write this as the more traditional for loop `for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) { auto& ev = events[i]; }`

Comment: oh I see; and the `auto` gives `ev` the `input_event` type; thank you

Comment: why do you resize the input event vector to 32?

Comment: @xinthose just seemed like a reasonable batch of events to receive in one go, at most

Comment: how do I convert `ev.code` to ASCII?  the codes for me do not match the ASCII table

Comment: @xinthose The hardware scancodes are mapped to ASCII by what is known as "keyboard layout". Look at the source of evtest to find out how you could do it. Here's output showing me pressing-releasing `abc<Left-Ctrl>`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/18657502/

Comment: Hello again.  I am trying to use `boost::asio::async_read_until` with a delimiter of `\x0D` (new line).  But I get lots of binary returns that don't make much sense.  How do you recommend I proceed?  I can post my code in a new question if you like.