# Linux USB HID device for Logitech G29 (kernel 4.4)

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, kernel, usb

I can't registrate a interupt event on an HID input device. There is no data update when I use 
 `cat /dev/input/event0 |hexdump` while spinning the Logitech G29 ff Wheel or pressing a button (ps3-mode).

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

> I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c294 
>   Version=0100 N: Name="Logitech G29 Driving Force Racing Wheel" 
>   P: Phys=usb-3f980000.usb-1.3/input0 
>   S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0>>>   /0003:046D:C294.0001/input/input0 
>   U: Uniq= H: Handlers=js0 event0 
>   B: PROP=0 B: EV=1b 
>   B: KEY=1fff0000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
>   B: ABS=30027 
>   B: MSC=10

Maybe there is a problem with the IN/OUT endpoint adress, because i could send  ForceFeedback commands to the device and it works.

> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c294 Logitech, Inc. Driving Force 
>   Couldn't open device, some information will be missing 
>   **Device Descriptor:** 
>  
>     bLength                18 
>     bDescriptorType         1  
>     bcdUSB               2.00  
>     bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level) 
>  
>     bDeviceSubClass         0   
>     bDeviceProtocol         0  
>     bMaxPacketSize0        16  
>     idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc. 
>     idProduct          0xc294 Driving Force 
>     bcdDevice           13.50  
>     iManufacturer           1  
>     iProduct                2  
>     iSerial                 0  
>     bNumConfigurations      1  
>     **Configuration Descriptor:** 
>       bLength                 9 
>       bDescriptorType         2 
>       wTotalLength           41 
>       bNumInterfaces          1 
>       bConfigurationValue     1 
>       iConfiguration          4 
>       bmAttributes         0x80 
>        (Bus Powered) 
>       MaxPower               98mA 
>       **Interface Descriptor:** 
>         bLength                 9 
>         bDescriptorType         4 
>         bInterfaceNumber        0 
>         bAlternateSetting       0 
>         bNumEndpoints           2 
>         bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device 
>         bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass 
>         bInterfaceProtocol      0 None 
>         iInterface              0 
>           **HID Device Descriptor:** 
>             bLength                 9 
>             bDescriptorType        33 
>             bcdHID               1.00 
>             bCountryCode           33 US 
>             bNumDescriptors         1 
>             bDescriptorType        34 Report 
>             wDescriptorLength     157 
>           Report Descriptors: 
>              ** UNAVAILABLE ** 
>         **Endpoint Descriptor:** 
>           bLength                 7 
>           bDescriptorType         5 
>           bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN 
>           bmAttributes            3 
>             Transfer Type            Interrupt 
>             Synch Type               None 
>             Usage Type               Data 
>           wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes 
>           bInterval              10 
>         **Endpoint Descriptor:** 
>           bLength                 7 
>           bDescriptorType         5 
>           bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT 
>           bmAttributes            3 
>  
>             Transfer Type            Interrupt 
>             Synch Type               None 
>             Usage Type               Data 
>           wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes 
>           bInterval              10

How can I register button or axis events to j0/event0. Any tips please!
Thanks in advance.

**Update 25.05.2016:**
Update: After some trial and error I could now communicate with the device using **usblib** and `libusb_interrupt_transfer(handle, ( 0x81 | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN), data, sizeof(data), &actual_length, 0);` 
I could use both Endpoints, IN and OUT. 
The next issue is that the HID Device Descriptor is UNAVAILABLE, So I get only 1 Byte of data for the steering angle and that is far to little for +-450deg. 
 How can I fix the missing HID Device Descriptor?

**Update 26.05.2016:**
At least I could fix the "UNAVAILABLE HID Device Descriptor" issue with a trick. Use `dmesg` to have a look at the kernel output. Search for the USB device. 
 `1: input: Logitech G29 Driving Force Racing Wheel as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C294.0001/input/input0`  
 `2: logitech 0003:046D:C294.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Gamepad [Logitech G29 Driving Force Racing Wheel] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.2/input0` 
 I was searching for a sub path in the 1: kernel output **1-1.2:1.0**. Unbind the USB device will fix the problem `sudo bash -c "echo -n 1-1.2:1.0 >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind"` 
 When I now call `lsusb -vd 0x046D:0xC294` I will see the HID Device Descriptor.

Comment: I had a related question with `boost::asio` http://stackoverflow.com/a/27827955/4056146 that could be helpful

Comment: Thank you, I will test it maybe it could help.