# Replacing select() with boost::asio::io_service

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am trying to replace the main loop in my program ( `while(1)...select()` ) with `boost::asio::io_service.run()`. 
The program has a couple sockets open, which were monitored by select().

The tricky part is that the FD_SET in the select statement has socket file descriptors as well as char device descriptors (for hardware input). In the previous code, calling `int fd = open("/dev/button1", O_RDONLY);` was enough, and that fd was added to the FD_SET.
The `select()` statement is able to monitor all of them.

So in order to be able to monitor the character device from `boost::asio::io_service`, I've been reading a lot about `boost::asio::stream_descriptor`. But I haven't been able to get it to work.

I've tried opening the device normally and then creating a stream_descriptor, and adding it to the ioservice.

```
void callback(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes){
    std::cout << "callback called" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    static boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
    int fd = open("/dev/button1", O_RDONLY);
    boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor btn(io_service, fd);
    boost::asio::async_read(btn, buffer, &button_callback);
    io_service.run();
}
```

However, that does not work.

Comment: Did you consider using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead of `select` ?

Comment: Does `btn` maybe get out-of-scope directly before async_read really does it's job (when the io_service is run) and therefore it gets destructed and the callback never called? We can only guess, the shown code looks ok, the error is likely somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show any code that runs the `io_service` (`run()`, `poll()`, `run_one()` or `poll_one()`). So nothing gets done.

A specific example that uses stream-descriptor to read from `/dev/inputN` is here:

[boost::asio read from /dev/input/event0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824573/boostasio-read-from-dev-input-event0/27827955#27827955)

It just uses `::open` to open a device (in this case, `/dev/input/event2` but it's just a filename you can change).

Note how it calls `io_service::run()`